# How do you add icon/indicators beside TreeView items via VS Code's API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I add decorations beside my `TreeItem`s like how it is done with the built-in git tracker with the `M` symbol here?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through the use of `inline` view actions. [Tree View View Actions VSCode Docs Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#view-actions)

An example of how to do this:

`package.json`

```
{
  ...,
  commands: {
    {
      "command": "myCommand",
      "title": "Command title",
      "icon": "images/some-icon.svg" // this is in the root of your extension project
    }
  },
  menus: {
    "view/item/context": [
      {
        "command": "myCommand",
        "when": "viewItem == myTreeItemContextValue", // Make sure to sync this value on each TreeItem to fulfill the "when" check
        "group": "inline"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Your `TreeItem` definition

```
export class MyTreeItem extends TreeItem {
  constructor(
    public readonly name: string,
    public readonly collapsibleState: TreeItemCollapsibleState,
    public readonly contextValue: string = 'myTreeItemContextValue'
  ) {
    super(name, collapsibleState);
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears for me, but only if that tree item is selected.  How do you get it to *always* show, even if the item isn't selected?

Comment: @Mike T that's my doubt too. Did you achieved it? The icon only appear when hover it.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The asker wants to add a persistently visible indicator besides each TreeItem; the key is the persistent visibility.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know this is currently not possible. There's no public API for that.

Comment: Would you mind expanding with more insight? It looks to me that the builtin git indicators use `vscode.window.registerFileDecorationProvider()`, and vscode uses the registered provider wherever **files**/URIs are listed in a tree, but the `TreeView` API doesn't deal with files, but with arbitrary items. Still, it feels like there should be a way to re-invent the wheel and create a renderer for arbitrary `TreeItem`s which requests decoration data from some generic decoration provider. You likely have a better understanding of the question than the accepted answer.

Comment: All I can say is that I have not found an API to add a decoration to the public tree API. However, VS Code is constantly being improved and extended and it can well be that decorations will be added in the future. I instead started using webviews in the sidebar, which is way more complicated than the treeview API, but gives you a lot of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from reading [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117499#issuecomment-785016406), you can use [`FileDecorationProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileDecorationProvider) and implement `provideFileDecoration(uri: Uri, token: CancellationToken): ProviderResult<FileDecoration>` to provide decorations for [`TreeItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeItem)s based on their `resourceUri` properties. For example, you can take a look at [how the builtin Git extension does it for repositories in VS Code 1.80](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.80.0/extensions/git/src/decorationProvider.ts#L32).

Comment: This answer is on the right track; ie, the needed feature is "Decoration"; However it seems that "FileDecorations" apply only to files; the question is about arbitrary `TreeItem`s - How to decorate those?